# Confusion about the definition of Radon Measure

Tags: measure-theory

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure), Radon measure is defined as

> Radon measure is a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets of a Hausdorff topological space $X$ that is finite on all compact sets, outer regular on all **Borel sets**, and inner regular on **open sets**.

I am reading a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582147/a-locally-finite-borel-measure-on-a-locally-and-sigma-compact-metric-space-is/1582479#1582479) on the $\sigma$-compact, locally compact metric space, that a local finite Borel measure is a Radon measure. It seems to me the proof shows it is inner regular on all **Borel sets**, which is stronger than the definition of Radon measure. Am I correct? What is the correct definition of inner regularity? I think the correct statement is

> If $X$ is a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact metric space and $\mu$ is a locally finite Borel measure on $X$, then it is both inner and outer regular (or simply regular).